# Store executable jar output in a variable in Perl

Tags: perl, jar

I need the retrieve the output of a Java program and store it in a Perl variable so that i'll be able to use split function. I am getting the java output using,

```
my @args = ("java", "-jar", "first.jar");

system(@args);
```

But how to convert this `@args` into `$args` variable (string) so that i can split the output from the string.

Comment: What about [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) funciton `$string = join(","@args);`

Comment: actually my jar output is "abc xyz" on console, i want to store both "abc" and "xyz" in different variables. How can i do that?

Comment: split the data with space separated. `@output = split(/\s/,"abc xyz");`  now `$output[0] `contain `abc` and `$output[1]` contain `xyz`

Comment: Try `split`: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

Comment: I will get the output from java only using "system(@args);" on console. How can i store it into a string datatype.

Comment: @john you want to store the result of the system command.?

Comment: this command "system("java", "-jar", "first.jar");",gives me an output on cmd (console) .I want to store that output in a string variable

Comment: @john Answer added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you need to store the output of the `jar` file. So use `backtick` instead of system. 
Try to know difference between
[system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) and [Backtick / qx](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)

```
my @args = ("java", "-jar", "first.jar");

my $result = `@args`;

my @ans = split(" ",$result);

print "$ans[0] $ans[1]";
```

suppose your result is `xyz abc`. `$ans[0]` store the `xyz` and `$ans[1]` store the `abc`

Comment: Now, I'm facing another problem. My java program should ask for user input and it ll be appended into "abc xyz" and then the splitting of these three will be done,
Suppose java is asking for user Input, and it is "123"
and the complete output from java is "abc xyz 123"
Then the splitting will be done. Its not getting output on perl. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to convert the arguments, but it looks like it would be easy:

```
my $cmd = join(' ', @args);
```

But wait... what if you add an argument `"firstname lastname"`?

```
my @args = ("java", "-jar", "first.jar", "firstname lastname");
my $cmd = join(' ', @args);
```

The result would be:

```
java -jar first.jar firstname lastname
```

Your single name argument would become two. The correct form would be:

```
java -jar first.jar "firstname lastname"
```

`map` could help:

```
my $cmd = join(' ', map { "'$_'" } @args);
```

(Extra efforts are needed if your args (may) contain `'` quotes.)

For capturing the output, use either backticks or `open`:

```
my $output = `$cmd`; # Multiline output in one variable
my @output = `$cmd`; # Each output line in one array element

# Read the output line by line saving memory
open my $fh,'-|',$cmd;
while (<$fh>) {
    # Do something with a single output line in $_
}
```

The last one doesn't need to parse the whole output into a single variable or array: It handles one line in each loop iteration. You could easily handle hundreds of GBs of output because only one line needs to be stored at a time.

Comment: I'm new to this script. Actually i want output from java code in perl in a string datatype, it will give "abc xyz" after running, my @args = ("java", "-jar", "first.jar");
system(@args);
By system(@args) only, it''ll run the jar file.
could you please give me a set of line of code?

Comment: As shown in the answer: If you want a single line, backticks should be the easiest way to go.